# Any type of jQuery effects like effects in this video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[this is video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLmPbCmaNZU)

from 9 seconds to 15 seconds.
If yes, please give me information about it. Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery polaroid photo viewer
http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/creating_a_polaroid_photo_viewer_with_css3_and_jquery.html